# Transfering color style from one raster to other rasters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, style, color-ramp

I have a raster set and I need to classify them using the "pseudo color singleband" with "RdYlGn". What I'm trying to do is classify a raster and copy the style to the others, but it does not work because it limits the range to the values of the first raster I used as a template.

Is there a way to classify the raster, copy the style to others and it refresh the range automatically?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this can be done using the QGIS api. Basically you can follow the instructions here https://www.gislounge.com/symbolizing-vector-and-raster-layers-qgis-python-programming-cookbook/ and then all you need to do is dynamically calculate the ranges to allocate the styles. I have previously done this in QGIS 2 where I had a process generating raster layers and had to style them dynamic and this involved calculating the extent and allocating ranges